# AspNetUserLogins table and maximum size of index keys in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

The schema of the identity model in VS2017/aspnetcore defines a table called AspNetUserLogins table to store external logins (CREATE statement below). It defines the primary key as a composite of [LoginProvider]  [nvarchar] (450) and [ProviderKey] [nvarchar] (450). The SQL server limits for the maximum size of index keys is specified at 900 bytes [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx). A note on that page specifically says

> "If a table column is a Unicode data type such as nchar or nvarchar,
>   the column length displayed is the storage length of the column. This
>   is two times the number of characters specified in the CREATE TABLE
>   statement. In the previous example, City is defined as an nvarchar(30)
>   data type; therefore, the storage length of the column is 60."

So is this key not twice the allowed size?

Sql Server Management Studio seems to think so....

> Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes.
>   The index 'PK_AspNetUserLogins' has maximum length of 1800 bytes. For
>   some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will
>   fail.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins](
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderDisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [ProviderKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Still an issue in 2020 with tooling going against a 2017 database I get

Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes. The index 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' has maximum length of 1412 bytes. For some combination of large values,

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they know...[issue1451](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1451)

Comment: And they just skipped fixing it again in the [issue 14503](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14503#issuecomment-610656783) so new users will always face this issue when they deploy to the production even in new .NET 5.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though this will cause subsequent issues. I originally created my database on my desktop prior to deploying it to Azure and there is a significant difference between the 2 databases. In SSMS, using the "Script Table as > CREATE table", the tables designs are:

Azure database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins](
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](225) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](225) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderDisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [ProviderKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Desktop database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins](
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderDisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [ProviderKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Note the `[PRIMARY]` references, I cannot get these into Azure. This results in the following error from a: MVC Net core 2 website using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;`

[MVC Net Core 2.0 error resulting from the inability to add primary clustered keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8vbL.png)

Comment: Would you like to upvote my question then? Some tit downvoted it because I found out the answer just after I posted it...

Comment: I don't have the reputation points from Stack Overflow as I'm too new. When this changes, I'll upgrade you're question.